# Read and edit List with ini file

Tags: c#

I have a List that contains several names and I want to add or remove some of those names with the help of an ini file. I prefer the ini file but if it isn't possible or just very hard another kind of config file is fine.

Here is the code from my ini class if it is any help.

```
private string _filePath;

[DllImport("kernel32")]
private static extern long WritePrivateProfileString(string section,
    string key,
    string val,
    string filePath);

[DllImport("kernel32")]
private static extern int GetPrivateProfileString(string section,
    string key,
    string def,
    StringBuilder retVal,
    int size,
    string filePath);

public clsINI(string filePath)
{
    _filePath = filePath;
}

public void Write(string section, string key, string value)
{
    try
    {
        WritePrivateProfileString(section, key, value, _filePath);
    }
    catch {}
}

public string Read(string section, string key)
{
    try
    {
        var sb = new StringBuilder(255);
        GetPrivateProfileString(section, key, "", sb, 255, _filePath);
        return sb.ToString();
    }
    catch
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

At the moment I can edit strings and ints with my ini file, but I also want to add or remove items in a List but I don't know how.

Here I add string username as an example:

To make the file:

```
    `_cINI = new clsINI(Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "settings.ini"));`
```

To write the file:

```
    `username = "";
    _cINI.Write("Settings", "UserName", username);
```

To read the file:

```
    `username = _cINI.Read("Settings", "Username"); `
```

`

Comment: @PHeiberg At the moment I can edit strings and ints with my ini file, but I also want to add or remove items in a List but I don't know how.

Comment: If you add that information to the question together with relevant code illustrating how you do that and an example of the starting data in the ini file and what you want the file to look like after, it's easier for someone to help you.

Comment: 'items in a List' explain what that means! Items as in objects or class instances  or items as string in a list<?>..?

Comment: @TaW, I mean like strings in a list like a whitelist for example

Comment: Have you resolved your problems?

Answer (score 0):

Elements in an Ini-File are strings. To create a string that holds a list of strings you need to decide on a seperator.

There are several characters that come to mind, most naturally the `Tab` and `VTab` characters: `\t` and `\v`. Others are possible, too, see below! The only catch is, to be sure they won't occur in the data.

Therefore `commas` and `semicolons`, which are often used, are not really good choices, when you don't know precisely what you will and what you won't store..

Let's do an example:

We start with a strange and mysterious list of names:

```
  List<string> EC = new List<string>() 
                  { "FX Huberman", "Kitty Collins", "Swede Anderson", "Cody Jarrett", };
```

Now we join them with a `Tab` character as separator and write them to our file::

```
  _cINI.Write("Settings", "EoC", string.Join("\t", EC.ToArray()));
```

And finally we can read it back, maybe into another list, splitting it again by the `Tab` character:

```
  List<string> FC = _cINI.Read("Settings", "EoC").Split('\t').ToList();
```

See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_character) for a discussion of other suitable control charcters:

> Data structuring
>
> The separators (File, Group, Record, and Unit: FS, GS, RS and US) were
>   made to structure data, usually on a tape, in order to simulate
>   punched cards. End of medium (EM) warns that the tape (or other
>   recording medium) is ending. While many systems use CR/LF and TAB for
>   structuring data, it is possible to encounter the separator control
>   characters in data that needs to be structured. The separator control
>   characters are not overloaded; there is no general use of them except
>   to separate data into structured groupings. Their numeric values are
>   contiguous with the space character, which can be considered a member
>   of the group, as a word separator.